# She'll be here any minute (now)

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

She'll be here any minute (now).

What does adding "now" add to the meaning of the sentence? When is it appropriate to include it?

Comment: Suppose we are waiting for my aunt to turn up, who is coming by bus but we have no clear idea exactly when. Alice keeps saying "She'll be here any minute" and eventually Bob says "Oh shut up for a while!" Then my aunt texts me to say she has just got off the bus. I say "She'll be here any minute now."

Comment: It's sometimes omitted in casual speech (imho the usage itself is "informal" anyway), but as a rule of thumb you should always include ***now*** in contexts like *He could arrive any day now*. Not that there's any chance of the meaning changing depending on whether you include it or not.

Comment: I think it is **added** in informal speech. It is just said like that. It can, however, be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

FumbleFingers is correct, using "now" can change the context a little bit however whether you use "now" or not, the meaning will typically be the same. To quote michael62511 from **[here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/36181)**.

> "In a minute" means "60 seconds later" or at least "in a very, very short time"
> "I'll do it in a minute, just let me finish typing this reply on HiNative."

> "any minute (now)" means that you expect something to happen now, but it hasn't happened yet.
> [@6:02pm] "Where is she? Well, she said she'd be here at 6pm, so she should be here any minute now."

Comment: FumbleFingers says it *doesn't* change the meaning, however.